# Reading a binary file given the data structure

Tags: python, binaryfiles, algorithmic-trading

I am facing an issue in correctly reading the contents of a binary file,  probably due to incorrect unpacking of the data structure (which is why I am here- because I don't know how to unpack a data structure, given different data types).

The documentation did not help me much, just led me to the standard list of data types and their abbreviations and a not-so-helpful illustration.

I am trying to understand the following code:

```
data = struct.unpack('<hlhcl6s10s11s10s2s10schc', b[i:i+66])
```

which "should" correspond to the 'last traded price' in this data structure (attached the picture): 
[Data Structure of the binary file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HJK29.png)

I can understand that the 6s , 10s , etc. mean the character lengths. But what is the significance of the 'hlhcl' in the beginning and 'chc' in the end. The data structure contains a 'long' (which should just be a 'h', according to the documentation)  followed by a lot of characters (which should be written as 'c6s10s11s10s2s1s10s12s10s12s'.

If you could help me write the correct sequence of characters to get the 'last traded price', it'd be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: where did you get that code snippet from ? Are you sure it refers to the same data structure you put in the link. I agree with you that this code snippet doesnt match the data structure at all, so it might refer to something else instead ? with the information at hand there is not much we can help you with. If you are right with the provided data structure you could access the last_traded_price_bytes directly as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: It refers to the same data structure. Can you please help me write the correct sequence, wherein I can extract all the data columns correctly. The code in the snippet is doing that. But, it is not doing it correctly (the columns are mixing up). (and is also reading some redundant columns, which I do not want). The file contains 1000s of rows of similar data structure, which I must loop through, on every line, to get the data of the same column. (or all the data could be retrieved using the CORRECT sequence).

Comment: Would you mind providing the exact binary data (66 bytes) that you're trying to decode and how are you able to manually decode it? I find it suspicious that your documentations talks about 213-byte chunks, but you decode 66-byte chunk only, meaning you've omitted some data.

Comment: That was a mistake on my end. I got a code for the 66-byte file which mistakenly I was trying to run on the 225 bit file. The correct sequence as I figured out should be '<hlhcl6s10s11s10s2s1s10s12s10s12s10s12s10s1s10s10s10s10s10s10s10s12shc' which corresponds to 225 bytes. I think this should solve my problem. There was some confusion as to which file the code was to be run for. Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the binary data on hand (`b`, right?) and you are only interested in one field, why can you not just access that field directly?

```
last_traded_price_bytes = b[88:98]
```

Might want to double check those numbers, pretty sure it started at the 88th byte.

Comment: Can you please help me write the correct sequence for extracting all the data columns? (from all the 1000s of rows present in the file). Please ask me any further details that you'd require for the same.

Comment: And your calculation is correct, the last_traded_price column starts at 88th byte.